# Confusion around constructor interfaces, why is the following code not generating an error?

Tags: constructor, interface, typescript

I am trying to add a constructor interface to my project and am quite mystified as to why the following code is not throwing an error:

```
interface PointConstructor{
    new(x:number, y:number, z:number):point;
}

interface point{
    x:number;
    y:number;
    z:number;

    move_1();

}

class TwoDPoint implements point{
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    move_1(){
        this.x =this.x + 1;
        this.y = this.y + 1;        
    }
}

class ThreeDPoint implements point{
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
    constructor(x:number, y:number, z:number){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    move_1(){
        this.x++;
        this.y++;
        this.z++;
    }
}

class improperpoint implements point{
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;

    move_1(){
        this.x++;
        this.y++;
        this.z++;   
    }   
}

function constructPoint(ctor:PointConstructor, x:number,y:number, z:number=0):point{
    return new ctor(x,y,z);
}

let a = constructPoint(TwoDPoint, 0,0)
let b = constructPoint(ThreeDPoint, 0,0,0);
let c = constructPoint(improperpoint, 0,0,0);


console.log(`Point x ${a.x} Point Y ${a.y} Point z ${a.z}`);
console.log(`Point x ${b.x} Point Y ${b.y} Point Z ${b.z}`);
a.move_1()
b.move_1();

console.log(`Point x ${a.x} Point Y ${a.y} Point z ${a.z}`);
console.log(`Point x ${b.x} Point Y ${b.y} Point Z ${b.z}`); x ${b.x} Point Y ${b.y} Point Z ${b.z}`);
```

In the preceding code I expect improperpoint instantiation to throw an error because it does not have the required constructor interface. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code showing where you expect an error:

```
interface PointConstructor {
    new (x: number): Point;
}

interface Point {
    x: number;
}

class ImproperPoint implements Point {
    x: number;
}

let ctor: PointConstructor = ImproperPoint; // You expect an error here
```

The reason why it doesn't error is because *it is okay to have a function take less arguments than the ones provided* in TypeScript.

This is for convenience. Otherwise you would need to do e.g `(evt)=>` for stuff like event handlers even if you do not need to use `evt`

```
window.addEventListener('resize',()=>{}); // This is an allowed use
```

Comment: great!! when you talk about the function, i assume you are referring to the constructor of the Improperpoint class.

Comment: Yes. A `constructor` is just a function that must be called with `new`

Comment: I understand this is the way the language is defined, but it just seems plain wrong.  Typescript supports optional parameters.  So in your event example, if you want `evt` to be optional in event handler function declarations, then simply declare it as optional.  If its not declared as optional, then the compiler should not be treating it as optional.